# Getting wireless to work on Arch Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, installation, arch-linux, setup

I've just installed Arch Linux. It's core, x86-64. My wireless card is:

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5001 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

During installation I took care to install "wireless tools".

How can I get my wireless connection to work from here?

Comment: have you tried the network-manager?

Comment: wicd is preferred over network-manager, not accounting everyone has the Gnome base installed, or ventures the orphaned xfce4-xfapplet-plugin)

Comment: i gave up on arch after the admin insisted i spent tons of time figuring out how to install it. So im not actively following this question up but I can't delete it either because it already has answers.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow official [Wireless Setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup) manual on [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org). Driver for Atheros AR5001 is called [ath5k](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup#ath5k).

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type

```
modprobe ath5k
iwconfig wlan0 essid "yournetworkname"
wpa_passphrase yourneworkname yourpassphrase > /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Now open a second terminal an type

```
wpa_supplicant -Dwext wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If this doesn't work, just type wpa_supplicant and copy the command from the last line of the help, it should look like the command above.

Now Switch to you first terminal an type

```
dhcpcd
```

Now it should work